# Ckeditor resize using unit

Tags: jquery, ckeditor

I wish to set my ckeditor to A4 size and A5 size by using a button onclick event with jquery.
This is my event code.

```
var editor = CKEDITOR.instances['documentformat-header'];
editor.resize(793, 1122, true);
```

This code works fine. However, I wish to set the size using unit (cm, mm, inch) instead of pixel.
So I changed my code to this.

```
var editor = CKEDITOR.instances['documentformat-header'];
editor.resize('21cm', '29cm', true);
```

The resize stopped working. It will not change the size and no error occured.  According to ckeditor 4 doc, it does accept a size value with CSS unit. My question is how do you do it?

[Here](https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor4/latest/api/CKEDITOR_editor.html) is the doc website that I looked at.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right. According to [docs](https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor4/latest/api/CKEDITOR_editor.html#method-resize) you should be able to pass an argument as `a CSS size value with unit`. I've tested various CSS units 'em', 'rem', 'vw', 'cm'. It seems none of them is working. I just reported this as a bug on CKEDITOR Github page. You can follow this [issue](https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-dev/issues/1883) to know when it's fixed.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, i will check out the bug report to see when they will fix it. I guess I have to use pixel for the meantime.